# SELECT username field without adding the field in groupby

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a small project using PHP(Laravel)/ Postgreql and i would like to select **username** field without adding **username** in **groupby**

This is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT user1_id, user2_id
FROM SESSIONS
JOIN USERS ON sessions.user1_id = users.id OR sessions.user2_id = users.id
WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1 OR sessions.user2_id = 1
GROUP BY (user1_id, user2_id)
```

Comment: What's the point of `GROUP BY` here if you're not doing aggregation?

Comment: Why are you need the `GROUP BY` here at all?  What happens if you remove it?  What results do you get and how do they compare to what you want?  Also, would this better as 2 separate queries?

Comment: @TimRoberts  i tried to not use group by, but i'm getting duplicated rows

Comment: @RocketHazmat once i add username field, i get duplicated rows

Comment: @RocketHazmat  i need users.id, user1_id, user2_id, username.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have a chatting application ( user1_id can be me or you, user1_id is who started the conversation first ),   User2_id  is the partner with who i'm chatting   
if i started the conversation i will be the user1 and you will be the user2

Comment: i would like to select the sessions that i have ( conversations ). including the names of people ( from users table )

Comment: The group by is pretty much senseless as you are also applying a DISTINCT on both columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments

> I have a chatting application ( user1_id can be me or you,  user1_id is who started the conversation first ), User2_id
> is the partner with who i'm chatting if i started the
> conversation i will be the user1 and you will be the user2

and

> would like to get just people with who i'm talking with

So - what I hear you asking for is a list of the people you're talking to, where "you" are either of the users (1 or 2) and the people you're talking to are the user who isn't you.

If that's the case, I think what you'd want is something like:

```
SELECT other_users.id, other_users.username
FROM SESSIONS
INNER JOIN users AS other_users ON (
  sessions.user1_id = #{my_id} AND other_users.id = sessions.user2_id 
  OR sessions.user2_id = #{my_id} AND other_users.id = sessions.user1_id
)
WHERE sessions.user1_id = #{my_id} OR sessions.user2_id = #{my_id}
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 3: ...RE sessions.user1_id = 1 OR sessions.user2_id = 1 INNER JOIN...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 112

Comment: sorry - need the where after the join. see update.

Comment: same issue :( 
invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 4:   sessions.user1_id = 1 AND users.id = sessions.user2_id 
                                    ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "other_users".

Comment: `SELECT other_users.id, other_users.username
FROM SESSIONS
INNER JOIN users AS other_users ON (
  sessions.user1_id = 1 AND other_users.id = sessions.user2_id 
  OR sessions.user2_id = 1 AND other_users.id = sessions.user1_id
)
WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1 OR sessions.user2_id = 1`

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, thought it might be good to rename the table and missed the references in the join. Updated answer to reflect fixed sql

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different users, then you want a `JOIN` for each one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sessions.user1_id, U1.username AS user1_name,
    sessions.user2_id, U2.username AS user2_name
FROM SESSIONS
JOIN USERS AS U1 ON sessions.user1_id = U1.id
JOIN USERS AS U2 ON sessions.user2_id = U2.id
WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1 OR sessions.user2_id = 1
```

Comment: your code works fine, just i still have the same issue ( i think i have logical issue ) because here i'm getting the user1 = 1  who is me
i would like to get just people with who i'm talking with ;)

Comment: @DeveloperDeveloper Then just `WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1`?  Without the `OR`?

Comment: @DeveloperDeveloper Or maybe you need multiple queries, one for `WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1` and another for `WHERE sessions.user2_id = 1`?  Then in your code, you can check for duplicates.

Comment: i tried to use `WHERE sessions.user1_id = 1`  but i'm getting just two records ( and i'm talking to 4 users :/ )

Comment: can you double check this link please, 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943717/how-can-i-use-groupby-in-my-query-to-avoid-redundant-rows?noredirect=1#comment121843810_68943717`